# How can a referee's decision ever be overturned?

Tags: madden-series

In Madden 2004 and 2005, and I assume the others, you can challenge the referees to review a call in the hopes of getting a better ruling, just like in a real football match.

How does this work in a videogame?  How can the refs ever be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

According to the folks at [Kotaku](https://compete.kotaku.com/turns-out-maddens-referees-make-human-errors-too-1798160593), EA has programmed some level of error into the referees.

> Very specific circumstances, like fumbles or sideline catches, may prompt a ref to get a call wrong in order to prompt a potential coach’s challenge.

It's worth noting that these errors (thankfully) don't occur in competitive modes:

> Electronic Arts also noted that this human error will not occur in the game’s Competitive play, the default mode for online games and tournaments.

The article doesn't provide a direct source from EA, but they do link to a [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-error-programmed-into-the-referees-in-video-games-like-FIFA?awc=15748_1578334588_d05a91885ea94b9225cf27ee75162414&uiv=6&txtv=8&source=awin&medium=ad&campaign=uad_mkt_en_acq_us_awin&set=awin&pub_id=78888) answer regarding refs/penalties from a former EA employee.

So "long" story short: The refs are programmed to occasionally screw up, in order to make the gameplay more realistic. This also applies to penalties.